# .NET MVC 3 trying to get RedirectToAction to follow the format of {controller}/{action}/{id}/{GUID}

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirecttoaction

I have to be missing something obvious here.

I would like to ensure all RedirectToAction follow the format of {controller}/{action}/{id}/{GUID} (e.g. http://www.mysite.com/report/edit/23/0975a566-983a-4414-962c-0ab1a921e89d

### **Global.asax.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Custom", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{GUID}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, GUID = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

I am using the following in the controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("edit", "report", new { id = id, GUID = getGUIDFromId(id) });
```

However, I just get the following result:

http://www.mysite.com/report/edit/23?0975a566-983a-4414-962c-0ab1a921e89d

I have had a good search on this but I've found nothing about this particular issue (probably because it is obvious).

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Just reverse the order of your route definitions:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Custom",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{GUID}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, GUID = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Remember that the order in which you  define your routes is important as they are evaluated in this same order by the routing engine. So you should always place specific routes before more general ones.